# Apache: create a virtual directory from .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I am trying to access files from a folder in my server from my webroot. However, the folder exists outside of my webroot. For example, I want to access `/mystuffs/myphoto.png` as in `http://example.com/mystuffs/myphoto.png`.

I have to do this through `.htaccess`. I can not edit the `http.conf` or add a symlink. Is it possible to do it this way? If yes how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without access to the server config then I don't believe this is possible to achieve using `.htaccess` alone. In trying to rewrite to a file above the document root you'll likely get a 400 Bad Request or 403 Forbidden (or simply a 404 Not Found), depending on the server config and the URL-path you are trying to rewrite to.

In a per-directory `.htaccess` context, the `RewriteRule` *substitution* takes a URL-path only, unlike when used directly in the server config, when it can be used to specify a filesystem path.

However, you could use a server-side script (eg. PHP) - in combination with `.htaccess` - that can access this area of the filesystem... that retrieves the required file and serves this to the client. Needless to say, strict validation is required to ensure only the required files can be accessed.